# Can't test inApp Transactions with Google App Signing

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing

Inb4 its a duplicate, I know the question is, but they are all older and none seem to help with my issue. Mine seems pretty cut and dry. I have an app that I build with a set of keys and upload to my play console. I have "google signature" enabled so they sign my apps as well. I have products enabled that work when the app is downloaded from google play test track. The SAME EXACT CODE BASE, signed with the SAME EXACT SET OF KEYS I used before uploading to the Play console does not work when I build locally and push it to my device. It says "This device is not configured for transactions" or something along those lines. I'm trying to build out my purchase flows but this is really obstructing me...

Everything is set up according to other answers. Same version code, products active, test track/alpha release are both available. Hell, the purchase flow starts fine when I download the apk from the play store, just not when debugging in AS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a true answer, or maybe it IS and my symptoms are a bug on googles part, however I seem to have resolved my issue. I'll confirm my answer if this continues to work throughout the day.

For anyone else having a similar issue to me, delete all storage/cache for the app on your phone, then delete the app (NOT USING THE PLAY STORE). Now, install the app from your internal test/alpha track (FROM THE PLAY STORE). Run the app, test the purchase. If it works, close the app and delete all of its storage/cache and the delete the app (NOT USING THE PLAY STORE). At this point you should be able to upload test builds to your devices using Android Studio and have inApp transactions work. Idk why or how this works but YOLO, If it continues to work ill come back and verify this answer. Hopefully this is something google can get streamlined, or maybe I'm doing something wrong and just don't know it. Feel free to answer and I can change my correct answer.